# Magento PWA: issue in starting development server

Tags: magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio

Followed all steps mentioned here (https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/) to install PWA-studio on my local.

All went fine except when going to start development instance using

`yarn run watch:venia`

Constantly getting this error:

> cat:
>   /home/narendra/.config/devcert/certificate-authority/certificate.cert:
>   No such file or directory Error:
>   [pwa-buildpack:Utilities:configureHost.js] Could not setup development
>   domain: Error: Command failed: sudo cat
>   /home/narendra/.config/devcert/certificate-authority/certificate.cert
>   cat:
>   /home/narendra/.config/devcert/certificate-authority/certificate.cert:
>   No such file or directory

Seems as if certificate file not generated, how can we resolve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem, hope if it may help anyone else.

The issue was that I was not having the root access and due to which it was not working.

** If any one else faces this issue **please delete content of**

**"/home/narendra/.config/devcert"** folder completely and try again with root user.

(In my case option to enter password was also not coming but on deleting this folders content at least I was on initial stage. )

Hope if it may help someone

Found this very helpful: https://github.com/davewasmer/devcert/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just chown bob:group2 folder  that has not got the right user permission and it works for me also.

Comment: Just one thing that I notice is that the chrome browser state as `Not Secure` but when I click to get info it says Certificate (Valid) not sure why Chrome says Not Secure ?